# debian jessie: how to automount from tty1?

Tags: debian, tty, automounting

[**Note:** before you mark this a duplicate:

There are several similar-looking questions in this stackexchange (which did not show before creating this question--one seems to get *much* better matches in the right side of the page after creating a question than one does in the top box after merely entering one's question's title). However none seem to work in jessie: they either rely on deprecated/disappeared packages, or don't actually work under jessie (as with [this good-looking but not-working "answer"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/86425/edit)), or don't meet requirements (as with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/11478/edit).]

I have 2 headful laptops: call them `happylap` and `sadlap`. Until recently, both

1. ran wheezy
2. booted automatically to X and a GNOME-based desktop: DE(`happylap`)==Cinnamon, DE(`sadlap`)==MATE
3. automounted USB drives: connecting a drive to the laptop caused it to automatically mount @ `/media/<user ID/>/<drive label/>` with user permissions

Very recently I attempted to upgrade `sadlap` from wheezy to jessie. Unfortunately its `dist-upgrade` got broken when the upgrade hung attempting to stop `fancontrol`. `sadlap`'s kernel upgrade appears good in that, when I coldboot, I see 3.16 in its GRUB menu. The problem is that, after booting that kernel,

1. `sadlap` boots to `tty1` rather than directly to X.
2. If I `startx` from `tty1`, the resulting GUI is very obviously broken and dysfunctional.

That being said, `sadlap`'s tty1 seems to be mostly functional ... except it won't automagically mount USB drives the way `happylap` still does. Instead I must manually

```
MOUNT_DEV='/dev/sdb'     # always
MOUNT_DIR='/media/me/it' # or similar
sudo mkdir -p ${MOUNT_DIR}
sudo mount ${MOUNT_DEV} ${MOUNT_DIR}
ls -al ${MOUNT_DIR}
```

This is annoying because

1. I want to continue/fix the dist-upgrade, but I also want to be able to record what happens, which I do by `tee`ing the upgrade output from the dist-upgrade to a file on the USB drive (which I transfer to `happylap`, my main workstation, where I do most logging).
2. I'm lazy.
3. The above `mount`s as root, which annoys, but does not seem to work without `sudo`. This is even more annoying since I know, from the normal/X experience, that "it doesn't need to be this way."

So I'd like to know,

1. What must I do to enable automounting from tty1 in jessie?
2. (probably related) What is making automounting happen "normally" (under X or GNOME or that runlevel or whatever is the relevant context)? If possible, I'd like to just call that from tty1, rather than reinvent this wheel.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm lazy.

You can create a script that performs all those steps (eg. on `~/.bash_profile`).

> The above mounts as root, which annoys, but does not seem to work without sudo. This is even more annoying since I know, from the normal/X experience, that "it doesn't need to be this way."

The traditional way would require root. From X there's usually a HAL/udev/setuid program that takes care of this. Given that this is just a temporary measure, I would simply add a line into `/etc/fstab` like:

```
UUID=<your usb uuid> /media/myusb  auto     rw,user,uid=TomRoche       0 0
```

The `uid=TomRoche` shouldn't be required, but some automounters need it to be explicit. The key is the `user` parameter, which allows you to mount it as a user (the mount binary is setuid).

The folder `/media/myusb` needs to exist, but you can create it once, as /media isn't automatically cleaned.